# How to declare a series of fields in one variable in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I wanted to ask what would be the equivalent of this in vanilla javascript?

```
    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'phoneNumber'   : $('input[name=phoneNumber]').val()
    };
```

This code is for a JQuery version but if I wanted to write something similar where I can declare all the fields in one variable or is that not possible in vanilla js?

Comment: Do you mean using something like `document.querySelector('input[name=name]')`? Could you better explain what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: internally this is exactly what jQuery does internally if `document.querySelector()` is available in the browser.  Here (@linke 169): https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/selector-native.js

```
var formData = {
    'name'              : document.querySelector('input[name=name]').value,
    'email'             : document.querySelector('input[name=email]').value,
    'phoneNumber'   : document.querySelector('input[name=phoneNumber]').value
};
```

Comment: would `'name' : document.getElementById('name').value,` be just as valid?

Comment: `.val()` is not valid in vanilla JS. `.value` is.

Comment: Nope. `document.getElementById('name')` would use the `id` attribute with the value of `name`. But that is not what you are selecting. You are selecting elements based upon the `name` attribute.

Comment: @RandyCasburn even if the input field has id="name" in the field?

Comment: Now you are asking **new unrelated** questions that are based upon information you have not provided. My answer is complete unless you edit your question. Alternatively, you can ask a new question. Please don't turn one question into many, it is frown upon. Thanks :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn There's also the old `document.forms` feature of the Web API:

Comment: @EthanHerbertson - Sure, but that is not the OP's question: **equivalent of this** Right?

Answer (score 0):

To repeat yourself less, you might consider `reduce`ing an array of `['name', 'email', 'phoneNumber']`:

```
const formData = ['name', 'email', 'phoneNumber'].reduce(
  (a, name) => {
    a[name] = document.querySelector(`input[name="${name}"]`).value;
    return a;
  },
  {}
);
```

Comment: It could be argued that doesn't really answer the question: **equivalent of this**

Comment: @certainperformance yeah but this is rather convoluted compared to just copy and paste. Honestly not sure what "a" is sued for.

Comment: @kaweki `reduce` is the functional way to transform an array into an object. Whenever you have repetitive code that's doing the same sort of operation with slight variations, that's a sign that you should probably refactor it. Copy-and-paste might be tempting, but it's not a good way to write code.

Answer (score 0):

If the controls are in a form, you can access them as named properties of the form and dispense with the *formData* variable, e.g.

```
var form = document.forms[0], // Assuming first form in document
    formData = {
      name       : form.personName.value,
      email      : form.email.value,
      phoneNumber: form.phoneNumber.value
    };
```

Which is likely much more efficient as it involves property access rather than a series of function calls.

Note that forms have a standard name property, so any form control should not conflict with that so I've renamed *name* to *personName*.